# Conditional use of __setstate__ in unpickling

Tags: python, pickle

So I have a class that remembers its instances based on an ID. When unpickling such an object there are two cases I'd like to handle:

1. No other instance with that ID exists, so a new instance is generated and `__setstate__` should be called normally.
2. When another instance of that ID exists, that object is returned and I want to avoid calling `__setstate__` on it.

Please take a look at [this class definition](https://github.com/Midnighter/unique-base/blob/master/base.py).

You will notice that currently I update only attributes that evaluate to **`False`** as a workaround.

I can think of two general strategies to solve this:

1. As in [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238252/unpickling-new-style-with-kwargs-not-possible), I could define another function that is called with the result from `__getnewargs__` and attach some attribute that tells me whether to run `__setstate__` or not.
2. If I can tell whether the class' `__call__` method was called from within pickle I could do the same.

I do not know if it's possible to further interfere with the pickling machinery and I don't want to subclass the unpickler.

Thoughts, recommendations, completely different solutions? Thank you.

Comment: I think you need to re-think your application instead; why are you unpickling more copies of what are essentially singletons in the first place? Or, does it *matter* if there are multiple copies instance with the same id? If these copies are otherwise considered equal and hash the same (`__eq__` tests for equality on the id, `__hash__` is based on the id) then they are considered the same for use in a `dict` or `set` for example.

Comment: The unpickling of multiple copies regularly occurs when you run parallel applications, since pickle is used to transfer them between processes. You are correct, however, that I need to identify the objects in `dict`s and could therefore just customise `__hash__` method. Then again, with thousands of these objects, I'm not sure I would want to add even more copies.